# sm-notify: bindresvport on RPC socket failed: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, ip, nfs, hosts

Can't figure out how to make sm-notify work.

I've added hostname entry with related IPv4 to /etc/hosts

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

# ...

172.21.10.1 vast10_vip1
```

But still sm-notify failing due to "EADDRNOTAVAIL" error

```
$ sudo sm-notify -f -d -v 172.21.10.1 -m 1
sm-notify: Version 1.3.0 starting
sm-notify: Canonical name for my_name '172.21.10.1': vast10_vip1
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.7 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.2 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.10 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.8 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.14 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.4 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.6 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.5 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.12 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.15 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.9 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.11 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.3 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.1 to notify list
sm-notify: Added host 172.21.10.13 to notify list
sm-notify: bindresvport on RPC socket failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

Pasting here `strace` output for more details:

```
103494 [00007f77fbd73027] socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3 <0.000014>
103494 [00007f77fbd72b97] bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(638), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:172.21.10.1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1
EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address) <0.000014>
103494 [00007f77fbd62fd0] write(2, "bindresvport on RPC socket failed: Cannot assign requested address", 66) = 66 <0.000019>
```

Could be that sm-notify attempting to bind via IPv6 address instead of IPv4?